# Using Regex to extract a specific word followed by certain syntax (such as parentheses)

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a very large document containing section references in different formats. I want to extract these references using Python & regex.

Examples of the string formats:

1) Section 23

2) Section 45(3)

3) point (e) of Section 75

4) Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1)

Right now, I have the following code:

```
s = "This is a sample for Section 231" 
m = re.search('Section\\W+(\\w+)', s)
m.group(0)
```

The output is: `Section 231`

This works perfectly, except that it does not account for the other formatting cases.

Is there any way to indicate that for `231(1)`, the `(1)` should also be extracted? Or to include the following section numbers if several others are listed?

I'm also open to using other libraries if you think Regex is not the best in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEzaso/2/)

```
>>> s = 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1)'
>>> res = re.search(r'Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*', s)
>>> res.group(0)
# => 'Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78(1)'
```

Explanation:

- `Sections?` matches "Section" with optionable `s`
- `\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?` matches section number/title (as you did it) and adds optional text in brackets
- `(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*` allows repetition of the section number patter after comma and space

**EDIT**
To exclude `Section 1 of Other Book` you can use combination of word boundary and negative lookahead:

```
Sections?\W+(\w+)(\(\w+\))?(, (\w+)(\(\w+\))?)*\b(?! of)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEzaso/3/)

- `\b` assures that you match until end of a word
- `(?! of)` check that after the word boundary there is no space followed by `of`

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what I would need to do to exclude Sections, which are followed by the word "of"? For example "Section 1 of another_book". "of" tends to indicate that it is a reference to outside the document.

Comment: @Mia If my answer answers your original question, please consider upvoting/accepting it

Comment: Yes, it answers my original question! But the edit doesn't help, it only excludes the (1) after 78, not anything else (e.g. output: Sections 21(1), 54(2), 78')

Answer (score 1):

There's probably never going to be a catch-all regex for this - however the following is quite close to what you want:

```
Sections?( *\d+((\(\d+\))*,?(?= *))*)+
```

`Sections?` = `Section` or `Sections`

`( *\d+((\(\d+\))*,?(?= *))*)+` = 1 or more of: 0 or more spaces, then 1 or more digits, optionally followed by 1 or more digits in braces, then optionally a comma and 0 or spaces.

The 'trailing' space uses a positive lookahead so it isn't included in the match, so you don't need to strip trailing spaces.

[Try it out](https://regex101.com/r/L9wl2H/6)